# Pandas: How to use method df.name.unique() dynamically to find all unique column entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This isn't exactly a question about how to find all unique entries in a column of a dataframe, since I know how I'd do that:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',delim_whitespace=True)

for key in list(df.keys()):
    uni = set(df[key])
```

What this is really about, is how to do it with pandas' own methods/functions dynamically and this strange syntax that I can't understand why anyone would use it:

```py
In [101]: list(df.keys())
Out[101]: ['id_cliente', 'id_ordine', 'data_ordine', 'id_medium']
```

With these keys, you can find their unique column values with the following syntax:

```py
In [102]: df.id_cliente.unique()
Out[102]: array(['madinside', 'lisbeth19'], dtype=object)
```

I can't use this method dynamically like in my iteration above, can I? I can only use it, if I find out the keys first and manually type in the `df.NAME.unique()` statement, right?

Why is this a thing? Is this method exclusively intended for interactive use from the python console? Is there a native pandas.DataFrame method for determining unique values dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it dynamically

```
df.T.apply(pd.Series.unique,1)
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you maybe tell me, if the syntax is actually weird or if I'm just weird? Look at my other comment if you want to know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for your df?

```
unique_stuff = [{col: set(df[col].unique())} for col in df.columns]
```

edit: actually I don't think you even need a `set` here. I've removed it below:

```
unique_stuff  = [{col: df[col].unique().tolist()} for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: Yeah I could do that, it's just that I found it weird that you can access a column of a dataframe by using it's column name *string* as a *code fragment*. Doesn't this mean, that when a DataFrame instance is created, the column names are used to create static variables, where the name of the static variables is also the name of the column? Am I the only one who finds this weird?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python